# validate the presence of at least one association object in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, callback, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've one small problem, I can't get solved. I want to validate that there is at least one associated model. Like in the following

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :things
validates_presence_of :things
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

This works fine when I update my model via `#update_attributes`, but when I simply set `@user.things = []`, I am able to get invalid data in the database. My workaroud to solve this is to overwrite the setter method

```
def things=(val)
  begin
    if val.blank?
      errors.add(:things, "not valid")
      raise SomeError
    end
    super
  rescue SomeError
    false
  end
end
```

But somehow this doesn't feel right. Isn't there a way to archive the same result via validations and/or callbacks, preferably so that `#things=` return false (and not `val`) and so that `@user.things` is not changed (I mean the cached `@user.things`, `@user.things(true)` should work fine anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator that will check the presence of things.

Instead of

`validates_presence_of :things`

You could do

`validate :user_has_things`

```
def user_has_things
 if self.things.size == 0
  errors.add("user has no thingies")
 end
end
```

Comment: That would be too easy :) It works when you call `#update_attributes(things: [])`, but it doesn't when you call `#things=`, because this doesn't validate the `User` or if you validate the `User` via `validate_associated :user` in the `Thing` model, then `user.things` misses the thing you are validating (i.e. `user.things = [thing,...]` present in the validation for `user.things=[]`)